# Twitter API for attachment upload

Tags: php, twitter

I am uploading attachments to twitter.I am using the below code to upload the image.

```
$connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' =>'https://example.com/image.jpg']);
```

The upload is working fine.But when the users uploading image with 5MB size the API is getting timed out.I am using the abraham twitter sdk.Is there any other method post to twitter without any issues?

Comment: Have you checked the [size restrictions in the API documentation?](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/overview) _"Size restrictions for uploading via API: Image 5MB"_. The API simply doesn't allow for uploading larger images.

Comment: Yes. It support upto 5MB.

Comment: Have you tried with a file that's 4,5MB? If a file says it's 5MB, it can theoretically be a few bytes over, which would make the API fail.

Comment: Twitter supports multiple file uploads.If i try multiple file uploads with larger size.It will get timed out.Which method you have implemented?